# jQuery slide jumps around on some divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I am building a little website so here is my problem :

I've got a first header div which contains header stuff. It has position relative and stuff inside is position absolute, but I think that we don't really care about this one.

Just below I've got my main container div with no defined positioning and some `<h1>` and `<p>` in it. Each `h1`, on click, opens some content below with jQuery slide.

This is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Fy2eK/). The sliding part is

```
$("#container_" + tabName).slideToggle
```

The point is that on the  which i called "buggy" in the example, and also on all other in my dev version, the jQuery slide is jumpy at the beginning and end of the animation.

I've done some search I found that I had to put a defined width but it didn't change anything.. Tried a lot of stuff already but I really don't find how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8s9VB/

```
.container_projects .mainSmallText{
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.container_projects .mainSmallSubText{
  font-weight: bold;
}

#container_professionalXP{
   line-height: 3px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#container_professionalXP .mainSmallText{
   padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: works on js fiddle, not in localhost. I don't understand, what it is, is it the margins, the padding, the width, what is wrong with slide ?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's basically the problem with the margin inside your paragraph. I've edited one part of it and added padding in the div rather than margin inside the paragraph. Here's one part I've edited:

```
#container_professionalXP{
    line-height: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top:30px;
}
#container_professionalXP .mainSmallText{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```